# I've created web application with cloud service, windows azure,right now i am deploying my web role on more then 2 environment

Tags: windows, cloud, web-deployment, azure-web-roles, publishing

I've implemented authentication in my web application, Now problem is like at the time of deployment i've to do some manual settings in web.config file
like; every time if i want to deploy on test then i've to uncomment local testing settings and comment to production setting and vice versa, so is there any way that i can change these settings runtime or dynamically at the time of deployment? because i've lots of environment to publish so every time do manually comment and uncomment of setting is not worthy

```
<!--LOCAL TESTING-->     
<add key="idaFederationMetadataLocation" value="https://login.windows.net/test.onmicrosoft.com/testMetadata/2007-06/testMetadata.xml" />
<add key="idaRealm" value="https://test.onmicrosoft.com/AadTest" />
<add key="idaAudienceUri" value="https://test.onmicrosoft.com/admTest" />
<add key="idaClientID" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
<add key="idaPassword" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=" />

<!-- PRODUCTION -->
<!-- <add key="idaFederationMetadataLocation" value="https://login.windows.net/test.onmicrosoft.com/testMetadata/2007-06/testMetadata.xml" />
<add key="idaRealm" value="https://test.onmicrosoft.com/AadTest" />
<add key="idaAudienceUri" value="https://test.onmicrosoft.com/admTest" />
<add key="idaClientID" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
<add key="idaPassword" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=" />-->
```

Answer (score 0):

So you just need to comment one line in release version of your web.config?
You can use [Web.Config Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Add the following line to you Web.Release.config file:

```
<add key="idaFederationMetadataLocation" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
```